# Javascript percentage calculation for each form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to work out the percentage value for each field in a form. However my current code is only working out the value for the first field or whichever one is focused.

I'd like it so that the percentage value only for the filed in the same fieldset

The current code works but i'd like to apply to to multiple fieldsets without them interfering with other inputs on the same page

In the snippet you can see that the two separate amounts which are editing each others details

```js
function percentageCal() {

  var $price = $(".form-item--invamt .form-item__input").on("input", calculatePerc),
    $percentage = $(".form-item__input-expand .percentage").on("input", calculatePrice),
    $currency = $(".form-item__input-expand .currency").on("focus", removePercent),
    $none = $(".form-item--charges .no-charge").on("focus", removePercent),
    $increase = $(".wrapper-types__percentage-value"),
    $increaseWrap = $(".wrapper-types__percentage");

  $($percentage).add($currency).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which != 8 && event.which != 0 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  function calculatePrice() {
    var percentage = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var price = parseFloat($price.val());
    var calcPrice = parseFloat((price * percentage / 100).toFixed(2));
    var newPrice = price + calcPrice;

    $increase.text(newPrice);
    $increaseWrap.fadeIn();
    if (isNaN(newPrice)) {
      $increaseWrap.hide();
    }
  }

  function calculatePerc() {
    var percentage = $percentage.val();
    var price = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var calcPerc = parseFloat((price * percentage / 100).toFixed(2));
    var newPrice = price + calcPerc;
    $increase.text(newPrice);
  }

  function removePercent() {
    $increaseWrap.fadeOut();
  }
}
percentageCal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="wrapper-types__investment">

  <legend class="sr-only">Investment 1</legend>

  <div class="form-item form-item--required form-item--invamt">
    <label class="form-item__label" for="wrappers[0]">Investment amount</label>
    <div class="form-item__input-labelled">
      <span class="form-item__input-label">&pound;</span>
      <input class="form-item__input " type="number" name="wrappers[0]" id="wrappers[0]" min="0" value="15000" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-item--charges-wrap">
    <span class="form-item__label">Charges</span>
    <div class="form-item form-item--charges">
      <label class="form-item__input-label-expand" for="percentage1">&#37;</label>
      <div class="form-item__input-expand">
        <input class="form-item__input percentage" type="number" name="percentage" id="percentage1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item form-item--charges-wrap">
    <span class="wrapper-types__percentage">= £<span class="wrapper-types__percentage-value"></span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-item--action-btns">
    <a href="#" class="button button--icon button--delete" title="Remove investment"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button button--icon button--add" title="Add investment"></a>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="wrapper-types__investment">

  <legend class="sr-only">Investment 2</legend>

  <div class="form-item form-item--required form-item--invamt">
    <label class="form-item__label" for="wrappers[1]">Investment amount</label>
    <div class="form-item__input-labelled">
      <span class="form-item__input-label">&pound;</span>
      <input class="form-item__input " type="number" name="wrappers[1]" id="wrappers[1]" min="0" value="13005.02" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-item--charges-wrap">
    <span class="form-item__label">Charges</span>

    <div class="form-item form-item--charges">
      <label class="form-item__input-label-expand" for="percentage2">&#37;</label>
      <div class="form-item__input-expand">
        <input class="form-item__input percentage" type="number" name="percentage" id="percentage2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item form-item--charges-wrap">
    <span class="wrapper-types__percentage">= £<span class="wrapper-types__percentage-value"></span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-item--action-btns">
    <a href="#" class="button button--icon button--delete" title="Remove investment"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button button--icon button--add" title="Add investment"></a>
  </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: help, to put a demo, or fiddle :)

Comment: Your `percentageCal()` function is never called

Comment: `$percentage` is a jQuery object, you don't need to do `$($percentage)`

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You can't have more than one `#percentage` or `#currency` on the page.

Comment: I've updated the snippet now so you can see the issue, I think it might be just a case of adding a .each and looping through the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of IDs, use classes and DOM traversal functions to find the fields in the same fieldset.

```js
function percentageCal() {
  var $price = $(".form-item--invamt .form-item__input").on("input", calculatePerc),
    $percentage = $(".form-item__input-expand .percentage").on("input", calculatePrice),
    $currency = $(".form-item__input-expand .currency").on("focus", removePercent),
    $none = $(".form-item--charges .no-charge").on("focus", removePercent),
    $increase = $(".wrapper-types__percentage-value"),
    $increaseWrap = $(".wrapper-types__percentage");

  $percentage.add($currency).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which != 8 && event.which != 0 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  function calculatePrice() {
    var $fieldset = $(this).closest("fieldset");
    var percentage = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var price = parseFloat($fieldset.find(".form-item--invamt .form-item__input").val());
    var calcPrice = parseFloat((price * percentage / 100).toFixed(2));
    var newPrice = price + calcPrice;

    $fieldset.find(".wrapper-types__percentage-value").text(newPrice);
    $fieldset.find(".wrapper-types__percentage").fadeIn();
    if (isNaN(newPrice)) {
      $fieldset.find(".wrapper-types__percentage").hide();
    }
  }

  function calculatePerc() {
    var $fieldset = $(this).closest("fieldset");

    var percentage = $fieldset.find(".form-item__input-expand .percentage").val();
    var price = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var calcPerc = parseFloat((price * percentage / 100).toFixed(2));
    var newPrice = price + calcPerc;
    $fieldset.find(".wrapper-types__percentage-value").text(newPrice);
  }

  function removePercent() {
    var $fieldset = $(this).closest("fieldset");

    $fieldset.find(".wrapper-types__percentage").fadeOut();
  }
}
percentageCal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="wrapper-types__investment">
  <div class="form-item--invamt">
    <div>
      <span class="form-item__input-label">&pound;</span>
      <input class="form-item__input " type="number" name="wrappers[0]" id="wrappers[0]" min="0" value="15000" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item--charges-wrap">
    <div class="form-item--charges">
      <label class="form-item__input-label-expand" for="percentage">&#37;</label>
      <div class="form-item__input-expand">
        <input class="form-item__input percentage" type="number" name="percentage" id="percentage">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item--charges-wrap">
    <span class="wrapper-types__percentage">= £<span class="wrapper-types__percentage-value"></span></span>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="wrapper-types__investment">
  <div class="form-item--invamt">
    <div>
      <span class="form-item__input-label">&pound;</span>
      <input class="form-item__input " type="number" name="wrappers[1]" id="wrappers[1]" min="0" value="15000" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item--charges-wrap">
    <div class="form-item--charges">
      <label class="form-item__input-label-expand" for="percentage1">&#37;</label>
      <div class="form-item__input-expand">
        <input class="form-item__input percentage" type="number" name="percentage" id="percentage1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item--charges-wrap">
    <span class="wrapper-types__percentage">= £<span class="wrapper-types__percentage-value"></span></span>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I've just updated the code to have unique ids and used classes instead, but the original issue is still there.

Comment: I've added a second fieldset to my example, you can see that it works correctly.

Comment: Looking good, thanks for the help. Is there a way to do it without referencing ".wrapper-types__percentage" multiple times? Can i store those in a variable or do i have to keep finding the closest fieldset every time?

Comment: You need to find the closest each time, because it depends on which fieldset the user is typing in.